# Nillable property issue after SOAP to REST in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

After adding a new API via WSDL, and converted SOAP to REST, Azure's policy scripts created an XML node with nil:true and trigger schema validation error when sending request.

It seems the difference between minOccurs and nillable is not handled separately so far. Any place I missed to fix it?

For example, for a field with minOccours="0"

```
<xs:element name="IntegratorId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
```

This is generated policy:

```
    {% if body.groundCloseRequest.clientDetail.integratorId %}
        <IntegratorId>{{body.groundCloseRequest.clientDetail.integratorId}}</IntegratorId>
    {% else %}
        <IntegratorId xsi:nil="true" />
    {% endif %}
```

And this will trigger followed error when IntegratorId is not provided in the request.

> Error:cvc-elt.3.1: Attribute 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance,nil' must not appear on element 'IntegratorId', because the {nillable} property of 'IntegratorId' is false.

- I test the scenario for element with nillable="true", current policy script will work.
- In this example, for minOccurs=0, just NOT generate IntegratorId in the policy will fix this issue. But manually fix each field in auto-generated scripts does not seem appealing here.

```
    {% if body.groundCloseRequest.clientDetail.integratorId %}
        <IntegratorId>{{body.groundCloseRequest.clientDetail.integratorId}}</IntegratorId>
    {% else %}
        <!-- just commit this line
        <IntegratorId xsi:nil="true" />  
        -->
    {% endif %}
```